# Create a transparent installer using Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to create an Inno Setup installer with a custom transparent background similar to creating an application in Visual Studio with a transparency color. Would anyone be able to guide me through this process or is this not possible?

Comment: It will take an awful lot of fiddling. I'm not even sure if Inno Setup lets you execute arbitrary Win32 function calls in the context of the setup wizard dialogs. If it doesn't, then you are completely out of luck without forking the Inno Setup project. Consider whether this is really a smart idea. No one cares if an installer *looks* cool, they care whether it is functional. A user only ever sees the installer once if you did your job right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Inno Setup proper.

You have to use some 3rd party clone or extension of Inno Setup for transparency.

Maybe [VCL Styles for Inno Setup](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) or [Graphical Installer](http://graphical-installer.com/).

Comment: I tried this unfortunately it is not working correctly, even using the examples that came with graphic installer. There is no image background.

http://imgur.com/a/Pgyvi